# Calculate sum of a column using shellscript

Tags: shell-script, arithmetic, csv-simple

I have a csv file as `text.csv` and want to calculate the total salary of all employees.  The data in it is as follows:

```
Id,name,salary,designation
12,joe,thomas,253637,IT,admin
25,miacheal,364829,software engineer
46,mike,silva,adam, 374829479, senior, software, engineer
85,amber johnson,3728291,IT
24,Austin barclay, 3701830,software engineer
```

I have tried using

```
awk -F "," '{ SUM_SALARY += $3 } END { print SUM_SALARY }'
```

but the total sum is incorrect. The real data has 5.5 million entries.

Comment: The salary field of line #2 is "*thomas*", which is a string, not a number.  Please clarify whether the data above is intentionally messed up; if not, please correct it.

Answer (score 1):

Your `name` fields contain commas but are not quoted, so `awk` will see differing types of values in the `$3` column for each line.  This would be the case even if they were quoted, but in the case shown here even a real CSV parser won't help.  Here is what I did to get around this:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS=",,*"; print 0 }
     (NR > 1) { gsub("[^0-9,]",""); printf "%d+\n", $2 }
     END { print "pq" }' < text.csv \
| dc
```

This first uses `gsub` to remove everything that is not a digit or comma within each line, then prints the value of the new second column, where columns are considered to be separated by one or more commas.  The `BEGIN` and `END` blocks make the data work with the format `dc` expects.

---

I used `dc` because I don't know if `awk` acts as a general-purpose, arbitrary-precision calculator.  If it does, you could instead do:

```
awk -F ',,*' '(NR > 1){ gsub("[^0-9,]",""); SUM_SALARY += $2 } END { print SUM_SALARY }' < text.csv
```

This case works much like the earlier one, except that `awk` is doing the arithmetic instead of `dc`.  This also uses the `-F` switch to set the field separator, to avoid an otherwise unused `BEGIN` block.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there's a migrating salary field, (that wanders from field 3 to 5 and back), two GNU `grep`s can isolate the salaries, and pass them to [`numsum`](http://suso.suso.org/programs/num-utils/):

```
grep -o '[, ][[:digit:]]*,' test.csv | grep -o '[[:digit:]]*' | numsum
```

Output:

```
382878066
```

Comment: @PremJoshi, Re "*no such command*":  `numsum` can be found in Debian's *num-utils* package, or it can be had from the [num-utils homepage](http://suso.suso.org/programs/num-utils/).

Comment: Lacking GNU `grep`, a single `sed` would do as well: `sed '2,$s/^[^0-9]*[0-9]*[^0-9]*\([0-9]*\).*$/\1/'` or similar. `num-utils` seems really neat!

Comment: seen elsewhere: instead of `numsum` just say `paste -sd+ -|bc` 
(which will work fine for non-extreme inputs)